# jQuery - Retrieve an Input fields' name, and then change it

Tags: jquery

I need to get the name of each input field within a row, and change it. I am having difficulty in finding the proper syntax to reference the name field. For example:

```
<tr id="row_0" class="dataRow">
    <input type="text" class="tabcell" name="_0-3" size="6" value=7.0 />
    <input type="text" class="tabcell" name="_0-7" size="6" value=7.6 />
```

I iterate over the rows and want to rename each td field:

```
var namePrefix = "AFS";
$('td:eq(0)', this).each(function(e) {
    $('td:eq(0) input[name]', this).replaceWith($(namePrefix  + 'td:eq(0) input', this).val()); 
.... etc ...
```

But this does not work.
The end result should look like this:

```
<tr id="row_0" class="dataRow">
    <input type="text" class="tabcell" name="AFS_0-3" size="6" value=7.0 />
    <input type="text" class="tabcell" name="AFS_0-7" size="6" value=7.6/>
```

Anyone know how I can reference the input field name and change it?

Thanks.
Vic

Comment: what does "this" mean in "$('td:eq(0)', this)", is this even a valid jquery syntax?

Comment: @ayyash it's valid jquery syntax. it's using the "context" syntax, which is kind of deprecated now.

Comment: Please take your time and learn how Stackoverflow works. There is no need to use `<br>` for line breaks, simply put two spaces at the end of line. Also you don't need to wrap code into `<blockquote>` or `<code>` tags, just indent by four spaces. If you create or edit a question, these format rules should show up on the right side of the page. Or have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help So you might now want to edit your question to correct the HTML markup.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the tips Felix.

Answer (score 4):

use the `.attr` and `.removeAttr` methods to change the name.

```
var elem = $('.selector'); //cache element
var name = elem.attr('name'); // accesses name attribute
elem.attr('name', myName); // changes/adds name
elem.removeAttr('name'); // removes name
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think this would work:

```
$('tr input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name', 'ASF' + $(this).attr('name'));
});
```